# how to handle null inputStream in a FlatFileItemReaderBuilder for Spring-batch

Tags: spring-batch

```
  @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Order> sftpReader() {

        String sourceDir = reconConfig.getWorkingDir().concat(FOLDER);
        InputStream is = null;

        ConnectionInfo connInfo = util.createConnectionInfo(sourceDir, "");
        List<LsEntry> filesToProcess = sftpSvc.pollForFiles(reconConfig.getPattern(), connInfo);
        log.info("filesToProcess: {}", filesToProcess);

        for (LsEntry lsEntry : filesToProcess) {
            String strIB834Filename = lsEntry.getFilename();
            log.info("fileNames: {}", filesToProcess);
            try (InputStream stream = sftpSvc.getFile(strIB834Filename, connInfo)) {
                if (stream.available() > 0) {
                    return getFileItemReader(stream);
                } else {
                   is = stream;
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                String msg = String.format("Could not process order file: %s", strIB834Filename);
                log.error(msg);
                log.error(ex.toString());
            }
        }
        log.info("No Other files found!");
```

return getFileItemReader(is); is where i'm having the issue, the stream is null in this instance.

hence i get org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.sftpReader' defined in class path resource [com/c4hes/api/recon/reader/SFTPFileReader.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader]: Factory method 'sftpReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream must not be null

```
    }


    private FlatFileItemReader<Order> getFileItemReader(InputStream inputStream) {

        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Order>()
                .name(ORDER_ITEM_READER)
                .resource(new InputStreamResource(inputStream))
                .strict(false)
                .linesToSkip(1)
                .delimited()
                .names(names)
                .lineMapper(lineMapper())
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Order>() {{
                    setTargetType(Order.class);
                }}).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method:

```
  @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Order> sftpReader() {
     / ...
 }
```

is a bean definition method that will be called at configuration time by Spring Framework to configure your reader bean. It should not contain the code of the actual reading of data.

The stream initialization should rather go in `ItemStream#open`.